# cakephp 3 postgres 9.4 driver bake

Tags: postgresql, cakephp, model, drivers, cakephp-bake

I want to generate models with bake terminal command. `CakePhp 3` is able to connect to my `postgres` database. All PHP extensions for `postgres` are activated (`php_pdo_pgsql`, `php_pgsql`). I checked `php.ini`.

When I run  the command: `cake bake model`

I have this error:

> Exception: Database driver Cake\Database\Driver\Postgres cannot be used due to a missing PHP extension or unmet dependency in [C:\wampPI\www\ticketHellocom\vend
>   or\cakephp\cakephp\src\Database\Connection.php, line 171]

Comment: paste the result of running `php -m | grep pgsql` in your console

Comment: I have done php -m and there is no module like pgsql

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the pdo_pgsql module for your php installation and activate the extension in your php.ini.

Comment: installing pdo_pgsql module and activate in php.ini file solution is not working for me.

Comment: Thanks, Jose. Uncommenting pdo_pgsql in php.ini works for me.